# RegEx for PreparedStatements

Tags: java, regex, oracle, prepared-statement

I am trying to build parsing application in Java, which parses Oracle's prepared [statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

As a proof of concept, i am trying to come up with a regex for setter methods found in the above link, for example: setString() , setInt() etc..

The setter statements can have 2 or more arguments along with parameter position.

```
setDate(int parameterIndex, Date x, Calendar cal)
setInt(int parameterIndex, int x)
```

So the Regex should be able:

```
tell me which setter method it is 
get the parameter position
get the associated values (including blank/empty string )
```

I have tried with this

```
set[A-Z].+([1-9]+,.*,.*)
```

This works partially, it fails for just 2 arguments. Empty values are not recognized as well.

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this one:

```
set(\w+)\((\d+)(,[^,]+)+\)
```

1. `set(\w+)` - searches'set' with following characters and return following characters as a first group.
2. `\(....\)` - searches (...). `\` is an escape character
3. `(\d+)` - finds numbers and returns it as a second group
4. `,[^,]+` - finds , and following 1 or more any characters except comma
5. `(,[^,]+)+` - finds previous comma+not-comma groups repeated 1+ times and returns last of them as a group #3

Comment: I don't think it match every parameter. 
Every parameter are not inside a group : https://regex101.com/r/JVyPbj/2/ .
I think there is something I don't get how your regex work... It should match ``2 or more arguments``. Could you provide an example of your tests for this regex ?

Comment: @vincentPHILIPPE I haven't understood what exactly is not clear for you? Even by the link provided you can find that `setDate(1)` returns `Your regular expression does not match the subject string.`. Change it to `setDate(1,2)` and you'll get `Match 1...`

Comment: @vincentPHILIPPE first parameter matches Group 2, and `(,[^,]+)+` checks if there is one or more "comma + not-comma" groups

Comment: @vincentPHILIPPE if you want to get all of them as a subexpression, you can just wrap that expression in (), ie `set(\w+)\(((\d+)(,[^,]+)+)\)`

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov,
It works well with only 2 arguments statements
Example - setString(1,value) => matches 1  and ",value"  
                 setString(1,last name, first name) == > doesn't match "last name"

Comment: @Kelly with a white space between `last` and `name`?

Comment: @Kelly what exactly do you want to get? Example: https://regex101.com/r/JVyPbj/3

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov ```setString(1,First Name) => should give method as "setString", parameter index as 1, value = First Name```. 
```setTimeStamp(1,timeX,Cal) => should return method as setTimeStamp, index=1, values = timeX ,Cal```.
Basically i am looking for - what is the method, parameter index and values. Values can have white space in between, or just be empty. Some of the oracle's prepared statements (example setUnicodeStream() ) requires 3 arguments - regex should be able return the same results , which is - index, first argument, second argument